# GPO apply when login using RDP

Tags: powershell, rdp, gpo, unlock

I'm actually working on a **PowerShell script** that enables or disable the Shutdown if the user connects by RDP, and it works perfectly.

I want to make it a **GPO**, i go to User Configuration > Scripts but the only choices i got is Startup and Shutdown, but i want it to work when the user **unlocks his account** (for example, The user lock his account to go eat and when he come back, he just unlocks, the **script run in the background** and he goes back to work).

There is any way to do that?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, i just added a task in the Scheduled Tasks.